# iScroll 5 has always this.y set to 0

Tags: backbone.js, iscroll

Looks like the [iscroll](https://www.npmjs.com/package/iscroll) is initiated correctly. I attach a callback to `scrollEnd` event and what I get on every vertical scrolling attempt is

```
this.x: 0
this.y: 0
thisdirectionX: 0
thisdirectionY: 0
```

For testing purposes I set `this.scroller.scrollTo(0,300);` to see if the script works properly and it does. Once I try to scroll further, the scroller reverts back to its initial position and it is done with smooth effect.

I use browserify to load modules in a backbone.js app.

```
var Iscroll = require('iscroll'); 

//for testing purposes to ensure that the scroller is loaded when the DOM is ready I do the following:

        setTimeout(function(){
            this.scroller = new Iscroll('#scroller', {
                scrollX: false,
                scrollY: true,
                click:true, // open click event
                scrollbars: false,
                useTransform: true,
                useTransition: true,
                probeType:3,
                mouseWheel:true,
                bindToWrapper: true
            });

            this.scroller.scrollTo(0,300);

            this.scroller.on('scrollEnd', function () {
                console.log('x: ' + this.x);
                console.log('y: ' + this.y);
                console.log('d.x: ' + this.directionX);
                console.log('d.y: ' + this.directionY);
                console.log('scroll end');
            });
            document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);
        }, 3000);
```

Once I try to scroll I always fire a `'touchstart'` event and when profile the iscroll script, `this.x` and `this.y` is always 0.

The HTML is complicated but I also tested without it and and I even disabled css files but of no avail.

```
<div id="scroller">
<ul class="c-list" style="transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.1, 0.57, 0.1, 1); transition-duration: 0ms; transform: translate(0px, 0px) translateZ(0px);">
<li>...</li>
<li>...</li>
<li>...</li>
...
</ul>
</div>
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was solved by adding `position: absolute` and `height: 100%` to the wrapper element